# Use a class in another project in same workspace

Tags: swift

I have a view controller defined in project A and would like to use it in project B.

What is the general approach to achieve this?

Project A:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
...
}
```

Project B:

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {

  func navigateToSomeViewController() {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by project? Sounds like thats what frameworks are for. Look into SPM Swift Package Manager. Also you listed this in swiftui tag. This is not a swiftui question.

Comment: Just an app project, not a framework.

Comment: So if you want to share code between projects thats what frameworks are for. Learn about making an SPM package. So you would create a framework and use it in both project A and project B. There is also copy and paste

Comment: So do I need to add a framework target in project A and use it in project B?

Comment: not exactly. I don't know how your projects are organized. But generally projects don't share code between them. If you had one project and 2 targets then you can share code between them no problem. But thats not what It sounds you have and probably for good reason. You would have 2 projects and a separate package (think of it as a separate project) that shares code between them. But sharing code really depends on a lot. Are both projects in the same repo?

Comment: `Project A <--- SPM Package ---> Project B` Project A and B share code from a separate (standalone) package. This package contains OtherViewController and everything OtherViewController needs. Note: The package can't access the contents of Project A or Project B

Answer (score 2):

The general approach to achieve this is to create a **framework**.
Firstly create a framework that holds your `viewController` named `SomeViewController`

Then add this framework in Project A & Project B.